ADB.exe dejó de funcionar en mi PC Windows 7 64 bits
¡Hola!
Voy a empezar a programar aplicaciones moviles utilizando flutter y android studio, cada que creo un proyecto en VSC me aparece el siguiente error: adb.exe dejó de funcionar:
Firma con problemas:
  Nombre del evento de problema:    APPCRASH
  Nombre de la aplicación:  adb.exe
  Versión de la aplicación: 0.0.0.0
  Marca de tiempo de la aplicación: dd5dfa32
  Nombre del módulo con errores:    ucrtbase.DLL
  Versión del módulo con errores:   10.0.10586.1171
  Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores:   59ae5046
  Código de excepción:  40000015
  Desplazamiento de excepción:  000846fa
  Versión del sistema operativo:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Id. de configuración regional:    8202
  Información adicional 1:  af31
  Información adicional 2:  af31c948b3a323d420b71d3e687dbd16
  Información adicional 3:  f52f
  Información adicional 4:  f52f539a04a3e46ffcd683bba4fdf018

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionar el problema? He intentado diversos métodos y sigue sin funcionar.
